# Android - Background of EditBox

Tags: android, editbox

It's possible make the same background on edit box in all Android OS? I want the background of editbox in a device with OS 2.2 be the same background in a device with OS 4.0. I want a background with a bottom line like OS 4.0. It is possible do that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually android provide us default editbox background in higher version 3.0 we can't create same background like 4.0 in 2.2.. But we can use images for them and we can create a custom android editbox look like 4.0 bottom arrow.

Comment: But when I found that image to set background of edit box? I don't find that drawable.

Comment: I found it. Is textField_default_holo_dark(light).

Comment: Hey Andrew I am unable to remove my question's please remove all  of them from your side Now I never Ask or post anything here..
Thanks..